# Calculating distance to the closest feature from different layer using Fiel Calculator

Tags: qgis, distance, expression, proximity

I am looking for the distance of the closest point (Layer 1) to my atlas object (Layer 2). I want to use the expression builder.

Example: I have a House, which is also the atlas_feature, on 'Layer A'.
I have bus stations which are on 'Layer B'. I want to get the distances to the closest Bus Station on 'Layer B'.

For getting the Name of the closest Busstation on 'Layer B' I am using reffunctions `geomnearest`. However, I also need the distance to the closest one.

Comment: Something like that : `distance($geometry, geomnearest('Busstation','$geometry'))` ?

Comment: geomnearest gives out an attribute (e.g. the name of a Busstation) so I think it cannot be used with distance like that, since the distance expression is looking for a geometry. Maybe something with the aggregate expression?

Comment: Look at the result of `geomnearest('other_layer_name','$geometry')`, it returns the geometry field / attribute of the other layer, so, geometry.

Comment: Hm, somehow it does not work in my case. Geomnearest gives out the value of an attribute in another layer ("Retrieve target field value from the nearest target feature in target layer"). It looks like this: geomnearest(targetLayer,targetField). When I replace "target field" with $geometry it gives out an error message. It works in my case if I use it like this: geomnearest('Busstations','station names'). Thanks anyway!

Comment: write it as `'$geometry'`, dont forget the singles quotes : `geomnearest('Busstations','$geometry')`.

Comment: thanks, interestingly if i use geomnearest('Haltestelle_KBS','$geometry') it gives out a multi-point geometry, as you said. However when i use it like this: distance(geomnearest('Haltestelle_KBS','$geometry'), $geometry) it gives me out invalid expression.

Comment: I am thinking the following: distance expression gives out the distance between the two closest points. however geomnearest identifies one geometry which is the closes point (e.g. one single point). So now we are comparing two geometries it should just give out the simple distance between them not the closest distance.

Comment: Yes, I tried and `geomnearest` returns the result as a WKT (string). So, just add the function `geom_from_wkt` as : `distance(geom_from_wkt(geomnearest('Haltestelle_KBS', '$geometry')), $geometry)`. It'll work.

Comment: it does! thank you. I am wondering where I can see the results of an expression e.g. that it is returned as a WKT?

Comment: In a QGIS expression builder (selection or update), you have in the bottom left corner a `Preview` text : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#the-interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following:

```
distance(
   aggregate(
             layer:='Busstation',
             aggregate:='collect',
             expression:=$geometry
            ),
         $geometry)
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but for me it's unnecessary complex.